# Comparing values from different views

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I got 6 views, which I want to compare. To easier this, lets bring it to only 2 now.

Views consists of 3 columns;

```
Schema_Name varchar(5)
Name varchar(250)
Hash_Value varbinary(max)
```

I want to compare `HashValues` between those views.

Then I can simply `INNER JOIN` them like that

```
SELECT CH.Name
FROM DB1.dbo.v_TECH_PVChecksums CH
INNER JOIN DB2.dbo.v_TECH_PVChecksums AU
ON AU.HashValue=CH.HashValue
```

and it will print all names from `CH` which meet requirement set in join clause.
But it doesn't work like I would like it to. Problem is, when you got some matching rows in both views, but there is one row in AU, which doesn't have it's equivalent in CH table. My query wont show this row from AU table. 
I tried `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, but then it shows also all records from AU, which doesn't meet condition.

Output which I want to achieve should looks like that:

```
CH_Name                         , AU_Name
DQ_1000_RunDQ                   , NULL                          <- they don't match
DQ_1001_SalesNullValues2Weeks   , DQ_1001_SalesNullValues2Weeks <- they match
DQ_1002_SalesDifference2Weeks   , NULL                          <- they dont
NULL                            , SomeRecordWhichIsOnlyInAU     <- this row is only in AU
```

CH should be some kind of pattern which I am comparing to, but respecting as it is above, when there is no record in CH, but it is in AU

Edit: Sample data
AU:

```
dbo DQ_1000_RunDQ                   0x5009848AA9BD90CD6C89CE99D3F8142E819279D1
dbo DQ_1001_SalesNullValues2Weeks   0x8838185422EBE35104DC92B24D898D54A97CF2EE
dbo DQ_1002_SalesDifference2Weeks   0xF24E2240DE0F122A47425D1B4D878DAC81ABA596
dbo SomeRecordWhichIsOnlyInAU       0xF24E2240DE0F122A47425D1B4D878DAC81ABA596
```

CH:

```
dbo DQ_1000_RunDQ                   0x1A1605A5FF101ED0D6ACFCFC996989D28DC92533
dbo DQ_1001_SalesNullValues2Weeks   0x8838185422EBE35104DC92B24D898D54A97CF2EE
dbo DQ_1002_SalesDifference2Weeks   0x4BCB9B19FDCD5409257A7375ABF907E45C15509B
```

As you can see, only second rows match themselves.

Comment: use simple cross join.

Comment: What condition are you referring to?  Your fifth row suggests that `right join` is at least part of the solution.

Comment: Not very clear. can you post sample data as well?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, it is a part. That's why I am asking how do I achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, but according to your desired output, you need full outer join

```
SELECT t.name,p.name
FROM DB1.dbo.v_TECH_PVChecksums t
FULL OUTER JOIN DB2.dbo.v_TECH_PVChecksums p
ON t.HashValue=p.HashValue
```

After edit :
If what you want is: When they appear on both and equal -> take both, when they appear on both but hash not equal > take CH , when they appear only on CH - dont take and when they appear only on AU > take it.

```
SELECT case when p.name is not null and p.hashvalue <> t.hashvalue then null else t.name end as name1
       , p.name
FROM DB2.dbo.v_TECH_PVChecksums t
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB1.dbo.v_TECH_PVChecksums p
ON t.name=p.name
```

Comment: It works partially. With full outer join, if hash_value from P doesn't match T hash, it will be moved to the end of the list and then, instead of number of T rows + one which is in P , but isn't in T, I will get number of T rows + number of P rows which doesn't match.

Comment: @Dodzik sry but I dont quite understand what you need.. you want all of T results no matter match or not, + p that appears on t? or.. what? update your question with desired output according to your sample example